# Nifi JMS input for Websphere MQ with TLS

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, apache-nifi, tls1.2

I am trying to create a nifi flow with JMS input to connect to Websphere MQ, running on z/OS. I am able to successfully connect using JNDI (with .bindings file) if the queue manager is not protected with TLS. I get unsupported ciphersuite error when I switch to a secure queue manager:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException[Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256],3=10.24.98.154/10.24.98.154:457 (10.24.98.154),4=SSLSocket.createSocket,5=default]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure(RemoteTCPConnection.java:2093)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:870)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1294)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:892)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:416)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:312)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1761)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(CipherSuite.java:228)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:79)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:2495)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure(RemoteTCPConnection.java:2084)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

I think the problem is to supply the `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true` variable to nifi process. I tried to add it into `bootstrap.conf` but it didn' t help.

Is there a any other way to supply `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true` variable into ibm jms client jar? I really stuck with this problem, so any help would be very beneficial. Thank you

Comment: What java provider and version are you running? What version of IBM MQ are the jar files from?   What ciphersuite are you specifying?   What CIHERSPEC is specified on the SVRCONN?

Comment: @JoshMc
com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar -> 9.0.4.0
javax.jms-api.jar -> 2.0.1
java version -> jdk1.8.0_161
ciphersuite i specify -> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256

Comment: The error indicates you specified SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256.   Did you use JMSAdmin to create a bindings file?

Comment: @JoshMc Yes I created .bindings file with JMSAdmin like following: "DEF CF(SecureQMan) QMGR(<q_manager>) HOSTNAME(<hostname>) PORT(<port>) CHANNEL(<channel>) TRANSPORT(CLIENT) SSLCIPHERSUITE(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)"

Comment: Please `edit` and update your question with the additional details you have provided, as you will see from my answer, those are key in determining the cause of your problem.  I'll upvote your question once those details are added.

Comment: Did the information I provided resolve the issue?

Comment: @JoshMc Thank you very much for your detailed response. I resolved the issue by a simple find-and-replace "SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" with "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" inside my .bindings file.

Comment: Thank you for the accept.   Note my request above to edit and update your question with the additional info you provided in comments.   I'll upvote your question once it is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that IBM MQ classes for JMS (`com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`) can work with both IBM Java JSSE and non-IBM (ex: Oracle) Java JSSE.  Ciphersuite names are different between the two Java JSSE implementations.  For the most part where Oracle follows the IETF naming standards and the prefix of the ciphersuite is `TLS_`, IBM replaces this with `SSL_`.

---

A table documenting how the IBM MQ `SVRCONN` channel `CIPHERSPEC` name maps to the IBM and Oracle Java JSSE ciphersuite name can be found in IBM's Knowledge center:
[IBM MQ > Developing applications > Developing JMS and Java applications > Using IBM MQ classes for JMS > Writing IBM MQ classes for JMS applications > Accessing IBM MQ features from an IBM MQ classes for JMS application > Using TLS with IBM MQ classes for JMS > TLS CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm)

For example the `CIPHERSPEC` you provided `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` has this entry in the table.

> ```
> CipherSpec                      |Equivalent CipherSuite (IBM JRE) |Equivalent CipherSuite (Oracle JRE) |Protocol |FIPS 140-2 compatible |
> --------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+----------------------|
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 |SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256  |TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256     |TLS v1.2 |yes                   |
> ```

---

***You are running into two issues:***

---

First, in order to tell the IBM MQ Classes for JMS that you want it to use the Oracle ciphersuite mapping you need to set the Java system property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings` to the value `false` (Note the default is `true`).

This can be done in your code:

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
```

or on the command line:

```
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
```

---

Second, when you use JMSAdmin to generate the binding file, it will by default will take the ciphersuite name you provide and "convert" it into the IBM ciphersuite name.  So when you specified `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` it converted it to `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` in the resulting binding file.

To fix this you need to edit the `JMSAdmin` and look for a line like this:

```
$AMQJAVA -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.outputName=$MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH/log -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=$MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH/trace -DMQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH=$MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.JMSAdmin $*
```

You will need to add `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` to the line line like this:

```
$AMQJAVA -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.outputName=$MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH/log -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=$MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH/trace -DMQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH=$MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.JMSAdmin $*
```

---

Fixing the first issue will allow IBM MQ Classes for JMS to use the Oracle ciphersuite mappings.

Fixing the second issue will allow the generation of a binding file that contains a proper Oracle ciphersuite name.

---

Currently the error returned is `RC=2393` which means `MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR`, this is because IBM MQ classes for Java thinks it should use IBM ciphersuite mappings and sends the `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` ciphersuite name to the Oracle Java which then returns the error you are receiving, `Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`, because Oracle Java does not know of a ciphersuite by that name.

Note if you were to fix only one of the two issues, then then the IBM MQ classes for JMS would return `RC=2400` which means `MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE` before even calling out to the Java JSSE.