# Nifi to IBM MQ ciphersuite issue:

Tags: ibm-mq, apache-nifi

We are  trying to connect to IBM MQ from our Nifi instance(nifi-1.11.4) using the processor 'consumeJMS ' and the controller service 'JMSConnectionFactoryProvider'.
The JMSConnectionFactoryProvider is configured as shown below:
[image]

The consumeJMS processor is configured as shown below:

[image]

The Nifi instance is able to connect to the MQ channel and receive real-time messages when the MQ is configured without any security i.e without SSL. However, on configuring the MQ with security i.e with TLS V1.2 and also configuring the 'StandardSSLContextService' controller service , we get the error as shown below:
[image]

```
 JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'XXXXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'XXXXXX.YY.com(1414)'.
     CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'XXXXXX.YY.com(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel 'ZZZZZZ.XXXXXX.04' to host ''. [3=ZZZZZZ.XXXXXX.04]],3=XXXXXX.YY.com(1414),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment]
     mqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel 'ZZZZZZ.XXXXXX.04' to host ''. [3=ZZZZZZ.XXXXXX.04]
     
     2020-10-28 20:18:24,300 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.apache.nifi.jms.processors.ConsumeJMS ConsumeJMS[id=c26ce2ba-] Error while trying to process JMS message: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'XXXXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'XXXXXX.YY..com(1414)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'XXXXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'XXXXXX.YY..com(1414)'.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').

CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'XXXXXX.YY..com(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel 'ZZZZZZ.XXXXXX.04' to host ''. [3=ZZZZZZ.XXXXXX.04]],3=XXXXXX.YY..com(1414),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment].
```

As discussed with our IBM Sever admin, they mentioned they have different ciphersuite setup on their  side. They advised us to configure same Ciphersuite on NIFI instance in order to overcome this issue.

Server Side Error:

```
===================
Process(12232.3231) User(abc) Program(mqmgr123)
                    Host(VMServer) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(0.0.0.01) QMgr(YYYYYY)
AMQ9639: Remote channel 'XXXXXX.YYYYYY.04' did not specify a CipherSpec.
EXPLANATION:
Remote channel 'XXXXXX.YYYYYY.04' did not specify a CipherSpec when the local
channel expected one to be specified.
The remote host is 'vmclient (00.001.00.05)'.
The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Change the remote channel 'XXXXXX.YYYYYY.04' on host 'vmclient
(00.001.00.05)' to specify a CipherSpec so that both ends of the channel have
matching CipherSpecs.
```

Comment: Can you get the full error from the MQ admin from the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` log?   I don't see a ciphersuite listed in you screen shots, the error should display what your application is sending.

Comment: Hi JoshMc, Server side error has been updated on issue

Comment: The key issue from that error is `AMQ9639: Remote channel 'XXXXXX.YYYYYY.04' did not specify a CipherSpec.`.  I don't know enough about Nifi to tell you how to do it but you need to specify a ciphersuite.

Comment: This question is similar but they used a `.binding` file for channel details and the ciphersuite is part of the JNDI def included in the `.binding` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539636/nifi-jms-input-for-websphere-mq-with-tls?rq=1

Comment: This isn't entirely relevant to the question, but rather to your privacy - you may want to do a second pass on blacking out that information, as several of those fields are entirely legible just by zooming in. Welcome to SO, stay safe!